# Updating a parent and its children without link between them

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing an issue and hope you will be able to guide me in the right direction.

A facility can have 1..n sub-facilities. Sub-facilities can have 1..n sub-facilities as well. And this can be a never ending relationship.

In the database, we only have keys to connect the parent and first children.

Here's a short schema:

```
--Facility has  : facilityid|parentid
---child1 has   : facilityid|parentid to facility
----child2 has  : facilityid|parentid to child 1 / no key to main parent
-----child2 has : facilityid|parentid to child 2 / no key to main parent
```

What I am trying to do is update a column named **value** and set it to true for a parent and all of its children and sub-children included. Right now, since I am only able to see the first parent and its children but not the sub-children, I can only update the value of those. But that leaves all my sub-children not updated.

Knowing that there is no link between sub-children and main parent, how would I accomplish that?

Here's a query that gives me a parent and all of its children.

```
WITH attributes AS (
    select fa.facilityid, a.id 
    from caip_attribute a
    join caip_facility_attribute fa on a.id = fa.attributeid)

select a.facilityid as parentfacilityid, a.id as parentattributeid, f.id as facilitychildid, fa.attributeid as childattributeid
from attributes a 
join caip_facility f on f.parentid = a.facilityid 
join caip_facility_attribute fa on fa.facilityid = f.id
join caip_attribute at on at.id = fa.attributeid
where at.definitionTypeKey = 'AUTO_CREATE_PROCESS'
order by f.id asc
```

The update statement is missing here but this is how I get the values that will later need to be updated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To update all descendants of a parent you can use a recursive CTE.

Suppose we have a data table with relations set using self-referencing foreign key column `parent_id`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    value BOOL DEFAULT FALSE,
    parent_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES t(id)
);
```

First, a query that returns a parent with `id = 1` and all it's descendants  would be like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE children(id, value, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT id, value, parent_id FROM t  WHERE id = 1
    UNION 
        SELECT t.id, t.value, t.parent_id FROM t 
        INNER JOIN children ON children.id = t.parent_id
)
SELECT * FROM children
```

Second, to update a `value` of parent and all it's descendants we can set `value` for all rows with `id`s in our select query:

```
UPDATE t SET value = true 
WHERE id IN (
    WITH RECURSIVE children(id, value, parent_id) AS (
        SELECT id, value, parent_id FROM t  WHERE id = 1
        UNION 
            SELECT t.id, t.value, t.parent_id FROM t 
            INNER JOIN children ON children.id = t.parent_id
    )
    SELECT id FROM children
)
```

Check a [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mJBVHQ6tNoieUjMmHhe4Z4/0)